# MySQL SELECT DISTINCT with WHERE

Tags: mysql

I have a table similar to the following

[image]

I would like to count the total number of unique `sequence` numbers for a given `user` and/or `date`. I have been attempting to do this by using `DISTINCT` in the following manner:

`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT sequence) FROM table WHERE date=2020-06-29 // should return 2`

The `WHERE` seems to be causing some issues because the response is 0. Do I need to do this using sub-queries instead?

Comment: Did you get 1 or greater when you ran `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE date=2020-06-29` ?

Comment: Don't forget to group by sequence to show our count correctly

Comment: 2020 minus 6 minus 29 equals 1985

Comment: @ThiagoDaAnunciacao I wasnt aware that this would need `GROUP BY` to perform correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your date with quote (`'`)
`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT sequence) FROM table WHERE date='2020-06-29'`

Comment: Thank you for the answer it seems to work correctly now. That said can you provide some explanation as to why this works but only with the `'`?

Comment: Some names and special caracteres aren't supported to use without quotes, imagine that you need to do a WHERE like: WHERE table_name.name = thiago anunciacao, is a kind of weird because mysql can imagine that thiago is a column.

Comment: @Newb4YouBB It's just the rule.  For PHP and C#, string must be enclosed with double quote (`"`).  In SQL, string must be enclosed with single quote (`'`).

Answer (score 0):

may be this query is what you're looking for

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT sequence) FROM table WHERE date = '2020-06-29'
```

or if you are not using mysql console may be you're using an editor try to save the date in the particular variable as a string thereafter call it
**like:**

```
date = '2020-06-29'
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT sequence) FROM table WHERE date = date
```